# I am new to spring boot.While I am running my Spring Boot Application I am getting below error

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting this error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Answer (score 0):

Spring is a Dependency Injection framework. Among other things, this means it provides objects to constructors (and not only) at runtime. If it searches for an object which is required and it cannot find it, an UnsatisfiedDependencyException is thrown.

For example, if you have class A which requires instances of classes B and C in its constructor, Spring searches for instances of B and C (also known as Beans) which may be used to instantiate A. If it cannot find at least one dependency, let’s say an instance of C, it throws the exception you’re receiving.